# PHPExcel add "sep=;" at the start of CSV file

Tags: php, excel, csv, phpexcel

Is there any function on PHPExcel that defines the separator at the start of a CSV file? i know that adding `"sep=;"` at the start of the file make Excel understand that the separator is a semicolon, but i cant find any function that does this on PHPExcel, not even a way before saving the archive, cause i put it directly at `php://output` to download it directly.

here's a sample of what im doing now:

```
$exportName = $className.'_'.date('d/m/Y H:i');
$objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->objPHPExcel, 'CSV');
$objWriter->setDelimiter(';');
$objWriter->setUseBOM(true);
$contentType = 'Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8' 
header($contentType);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$exportName.'.'.$this->type.'"');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: There isn't, because it isn't officially recognised as part of the csv file specification; although it would probably be a useful addition to have a `includeSeparator()` method (or similar) to indicate whether it should be set in the file or not

Comment: i know, libre office doesnt understand the separator, but my client mostly uses excel, i think that i will set the delimiter to the default to their system only, which is semicolon on this case.

Comment: Give me a couple of days, and I'll add a flag (and appropriate methods) that allows you to enable it for inclusion in the csv output in the develop branch

Answer (score 1):

Try adding setIncludeSeparatorLine work like a charm

```
$writer = new Csv($spreadsheet);
$writer->setDelimiter(';');
$writer->setEnclosure('"');
$writer->setLineEnding("\r\n");
$writer->setIncludeSeparatorLine(true);
```